# I updated Android Studio and now gradle project sync fails

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I updated Android Studio and now I get these errors: 
1. Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly.
2. Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 403 Request blocked by Privoxy"

Answer (score 6):

I add this line "systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*|localhost" in gradle.properties. Works !!!

Answer (score 0):

Just 1.close your IDE(Android Studio) 2.delete .gradle folder in C:/Users/Your User.gradle in Windows and 3.open your IDE and enjoy

**Updated: 2020/04/21**

this problem could be fixed by delete gradle.properties file in C:/Users/Your User/.gradle folder

Answer (score 0):

following option solved "Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 403 Request blocked by Privoxy" issue

In Android Studio: From the menu bar, click File > Settings (on macOS, click Android Studio > Preferences). In the left pane, click Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy. Select No proxy radio button.
deleted gradle.properties file in C:/Users/Your User/.gradle folder

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using two proxies at a time (even though I disabled first)

If you have a `$HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties` files, make sure your proxy matched the content of this file.

then:

- Prefer a proxy [that bypasses the link giving 403]
- Or a strong protocol of VPN (Kerio, ...)

(Discovered it by running with `--debug` option