# I can not use Build apk(s) for application after moving it to another pc

Tags: android-studio, sdk, neshan-map

I have a problem in android studio, I used `neshan` map platform instead of google map, It was working correctly, then I moved the source to another pc, the sync works without any error, but when I want to use `build apk(s)` android studio show an error:
Could not GET 'https://maven.neshan.org/artifactory/public-maven/neshan-android-sdk/mobile-

```
sdk/1.0.0/mobile-sdk-1.0.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Request blocked by Privoxy
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

I searched in google for three days but did not find any solution for this problem.
Then I changed `gradle.properties` like this:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=fodev.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8118
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.jitpack.io, *.maven.org
systemProp.https.proxyHost=fodev.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8118
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.jitpack.io, *.maven.org
```

but I receive that error again.

Then I download the `sdk/1.0.0/mobile-sdk-1.0.0.pom` file but I don't know how to import it to android studio. can any one help me?

Comment: The error says Privoxy block the request, so just whitelist the domain on Privoxy setting.

Comment: wow! Thank you Martheen, I searched for privoxy  and find a answer that works fine, link:      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60604670/i-updated-android-studio-and-now-gradle-project-sync-fails

Answer (score 0):

I find an answer from this link and build apk(s) is working!

[I updated Android Studio and now gradle project sync fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60604670/i-updated-android-studio-and-now-gradle-project-sync-fails)

I add this line "systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*|localhost" in gradle.properties. Works !!!