# Why MapSdk library implementation has error in MapBox

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, mapbox

I want to implement the MapBox MapSdk in android but I get the following error:

```
Failed to resolve: com.mapbox.maps:android:10.9.1
Show in Project Structure dialog
Show Details
Affected Modules: app, triplistdetail
```

[image]

I have done the configs exactly as in the document.

My setting.gradle:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = "mapbox"
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN
            }
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle project:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath(Hilt.hiltAndroidGradlePlugin)
        classpath(Kotlin.kotlinSerialization)
    }
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

plugins {
    id (Plugins.androidApplication).version(Plugins.androidPluginVersion).apply(false)
    id (Plugins.androidLibrary).version(Plugins.androidPluginVersion).apply(false)
    id (Plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid).version(Plugins.jetbrainsPluginVersion).apply(false)
    id (Plugins.kotlinPluginSerialization).version(Plugins.jetbrainsPluginVersion).apply(false)
    id (Plugins.daggerHiltAndroid).version(Hilt.hiltVersion).apply(false)
}
```

Secret key:  ///this is the temporary secret code

```
MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN=sk....
```

secret key config:
[image]

Finall library implementation:

```
    private const val mapBoxVersion = "10.9.1"
    const val mapBox = "com.mapbox.maps:android:$mapBoxVersion"

    with(MapBox){
        implementation(mapBox)
    }
```

Comment: Did you try the following ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60604670/i-updated-android-studio-and-now-gradle-project-sync-fails

Comment: @Hotellina test I was correct solution